# Set New Dataframe Column If Existing Columns Value Starts With A Number

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I create a new column (like below) to separate out values if they start with a number? I've attempted utilizing variations of isdigit() and slicing the value to look at the first character [:1], but I haven't been able to get this to work. `df.apply(lambda x: x if x['attr'][:1].isdigit()==False)`

**Dummy Data:**

```
data = {'Name':['Bob','Kyle','Kevin'],
        'attr':['abc123','1230','(ab)']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
data = {'Name':['Bob','Kyle','Kevin'],
        'attr':['abc123','1230','(ab)'],
        'num_start':[None,'1230',None],
         'str_start':['abc123',None,'(ab)']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://datagy.io/pandas-conditional-column/

Comment: Unfortunately does not help me @jspcal

Comment: I suspect this may be some form of [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/); while an interesting question as posed, what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use a regex: [`r'^\d'`](https://regexr.com/72fu7)

`pandas.Series.str.startswith` would work, except that it doesn't accept a regex; instead, use `pandas.Series.str.contains` and anchor to the start of the string with `^`, then search for a numeric digit with `\d`.

`df.attr.str.contains(r'^\d')` gives a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) of `True/False` values; for rows where it is `True`, the value goes to the `num_start` column, and where it is `False`, the value goes to the `str_start` column.

From the first `df`,

```py
condition = df.attr.str.contains(r'^\d')
df['num_start'] = df.attr.where(condition, other=None)
df['str_start'] = df.attr.where(~condition, other=None)
```

gives

```
    Name    attr num_start str_start
0    Bob  abc123      None    abc123
1   Kyle    1230      1230      None
2  Kevin    (ab)      None      (ab)
```

##### Postscript

If this is an x-y problem, where you want to handle the rows differently depending on whether the `attr` starts with a digit or no, consider something like

```py
for starts_with_num, group in df.groupby(condition):
    # logic
    if starts_with_num:
        # do the thing (attr starts with a digit)
    else:
        # do the other thing (attr doesn't start with a digit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
cond = df['attr'].str.replace('[^\w\d]', '').str.contains(r'^\d')

df['num_start'] = np.where(cond, df['attr'], None)
df['str_start'] = np.where(cond, None, df['attr'])
```

Output:

```
    Name    attr num_start str_start
0    Bob  abc123      None    abc123
1   Kyle    1230      1230      None
2  Kevin    (ab)      None      (ab)
```